# Dijkstra Time Complexity using Binary Heap

Tags: algorithm, graph

Let G(V, E)be an undirected graph with positive edge weights. Dijkstra’s single source shortest path algorithm can be implemented using the binary heap data structure with time complexity:

```
 1. O(|V|^2)
 2. O(|E|+|V|log|V|)
 3. O(|V|log|V|)
 4. O((|E|+|V|)log|V|)
```

========================================================================

Correct answer is -

> 4. O((|E|+|V|)log|V|)

=========================================================================

My Approach is as follows -

```
O(V+V+VlogV+ElogV) = O(ElogV)
```

- `O(V)` to intialize.
- `O(V)` to Build Heap.
- `VlogV` to perform Extract_Min
- `ElogV` to perform Decrease Key

> Now, as I get O(ElogV) and when I see options, a part of me says the
>   correct one is O(VlogV) because for a sparse Graph |V| = |E|, but as I
>   said the correct answer is O((|E|+|V|)log|V|). So, where am I going
>   wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you are correct that the complexity is actually **O(E log V)**.

Since **E** can be up to **(V^2 - V)/2**, this is not the same as **O(V log V)**.

If every vertex has an edge, then **V <= 2E**, so in that case, **O(E log V) = O( (E+V) log V)**.  That is the usual case, and corresponds to the "correct" answer.

But technically, **O(E log V)** is not the same as **O( (E+V) log V)**, because there may be a whole bunch of disconnected vertexes in **V**. When that is the case, however, Dijkstra's algorithm will never see all those vertexes, since it only finds vertexes connected to the single source. So, when the difference between these two complexities is important, you are right and the "correct answer" is not.

Comment: Thanks dear, Matt.

Comment: I don't see why the answer is not `O(V + E logV)`. I asked about that but I haven't gotten a satisfying reponse: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3683910/time-complexity-of-dijkstras-algorithm

Comment: @martinkunev I think the response you got over there was not too bad, but I added one that might be clearer.

Comment: I agree with @martinkunev that a more optimized implementation can achieve O(V + E log V) complexity for all graphs: V steps for initializing distances to all vertices; then only insert or update reached nodes from there. If your graph is completely disconnected then you only do O(V) work. If your graph is completely connected then you do O(E log V) work. So, O(V + E log V) for all possible graphs. Indeed, it can be reduced to O(E log V) for all graphs, by using an initially empty hashtable of reached vertices, so you don't have to initialize the distance to all V vertices right off the bat.

Answer (score 1):

Let me put it this way.The correct answer is O((E+V)logV)).If the graph has the source vertex not reachable to all of the other vertices,VlogV could be more than ElogV.But if we assume that the source vertex is reachable to every other vertex, the graph will have at least V-1 edges.So,it will be ElogV.It is more to do with the reachability from the source vertex.